# Distribution of l occurrences in a row in the limit of infinite trials

Tags: conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, runs

**The events:**

Let each event have two possible outcomes: $A$ with probability $p$; $B$ with probability $1-p$

The events are independent

**Problem:**

In the limit of the number of trials $N$ tending to infinity, what is the (normalised) distribution of `lengths' $l$ of clusters of $A$ events?

An example:

$AAABABAABBAAA$ has four lengths $l$: 3, 1, 2, 3.

Hence $P(l=3) = 1/2$, $P(l=1)=1/4$ and $P(l=2) = 1/4$.

**Why I'm stuck**:

What is confusing me is trying to compute the distribution of $l$ when I have only the usual binomial results for the number of $A$ events, etc. The probability of having $l$ events in a row all be $A$ is trivial to compute ($p^l$), but computing the probability that a given `chain' of $A$ events is of length $l$ is confusing me! Naively I would say that a chain of length $l$ has weight $p^l$, and hence $P(l) = p^l/\sum_lp^l$ - but I am worried I might be thinking too simplistically...

Comment: A "cluster of $A$ events" is precisely what the *Geometric Distribution* is concerned with.